# Filling gaps in query return value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database that has columns as follows.

```
Id    Date              Value
1    12/01/2010 09:30   127.31
1    12/01/2010 09:31   133.41
1    12/01/2010 09:32   147.54
1    12/01/2010 09:34   155.66
```

Essentially, I store values corresponding to timestamps. However, if a value is 0, I dont store it(Its a really large database, and 0's occur frequently, so we decided to not include those rows to save space). In the above example, `12/01/2010 09:33` has a 0 value so its not stored. However when a user queries the database, he does something like

```
select * from table where Id = '1' and Date > to_date('12/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY')`
```

and I need to fill in the gaps and mention timestamps with 0 values. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you definitely need to do this in the database rather than at the client side?

Comment: How do you decide not to store a zero ? - can you not change this so it doesn't affect the timestamp column or are you wanting to exclude timestams that are 00/00/0000/ 00:00

Comment: @JonSkeet, Hopefully. I'm open to alternate suggestions. I'd like to see what works.

Comment: @Rob I'm not sure I follow. The 0 value data is essentially useless. But when the row is missing, the client may assume we dont have the data so we just need fillers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
select 
   nvl(b.id,1) as id, 
   alldates.Date as Date, 
   nvl(b.value,0) as value
from 
  (select level/1440 + to_date('12/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY') as Date
        from dual
        connect by level < 1440 --one day
   ) alldates
  left join
  (select * from table where Id = '1' and Date > to_date('12/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY') b
  on alldates.Date = b.Date
```

**UPDATED**(response to comment):

```
select 
   nvl(b.id,1) as id, 
   alldates.Date as Date, 
   nvl(b.value,0) as value,
   nvl(b.value, lag(b.value) over (order by b.Date nulls last)) last_valid_value
from 
  (select level/1440 + to_date('12/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY') as Date
        from dual
        connect by level < 1440 --one day
   ) alldates
  left join
  (select * from table where Id = '1' and Date > to_date('12/01/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY') b
  on alldates.Date = b.Date
```

Comment: This works beautifully. Thanks! Can I make it generate timestamps from only 09:30 to 16:00?

Comment: yes, you should do some number operations: set start date at 09:30, and generate the number of minutes until 16:00 :)

Comment: Hi, I have an additional question. Instead of replacing missing entries with a zero, can I replace its values with the last valid entry above it?

Comment: I would look at using `LAST_VALUE` with the `IGNORE NULLS` clause rather than `LAG` to get the last valid value as I don't think `LAG` will return the correct value when there are two consecutive missing values.

Comment: And the analytic function may need to partition on ID, although without knowing the data I can't be sure of that. It's not needed in this case because the ID column is specified in the where condition but may be needed in the more general case

Comment: @Aks I updated my answer before your last comment - is the second query @MikeyByCrikey `partition by id` will be usefull if he ask for more ids, but he query for specific id. And `lag` is ok because there is an order by Date nulls last - this will get the previous non-null Date. Anyway, your comments are usefull, thanks!

Comment: @FlorinGhita, The query takes the last entry of the day and replaces it in the missing values. I was hoping for eg, if 9:33 was missing..it would replace it with 9:32's data. I apologize if you misunderstood

Comment: I've modified your query to get what I needed. Thanks for your help :)